# How do i format output number in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, number-formatting

I have a table with two columns

Product (Varchar 20 ), length (float 100). I want to show the output of length such that it shows upto 3 decimal places irrespective on the number of digits in integral part of the length.

I have done the following

```
SELECT product,to_char(length,'999D999') from productdetails
```

However if one of the records has a number which has 4 digits in integral part of the number it returns ########. The above works only for data which has upto 3 digits in the integral part. How do i make it in such a way so that it returns 3 decimal digits irrespective of the number of digits in the integral part?

Note: ROUND(length,3) does not give decimals upto 3 digits if the length is a perfect integer.

Comment: So, for example, what result would you want to get for a number like 1234.567?

Comment: I would like it to show 1234.567

Answer (score 1):

Use:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1a79/16/0)**

```
SELECT 
  Product,
  length,
  to_char(length,'999999999999999D999')
FROM tab
```

Comment: @SqlFiddleDemo : ] This would again fail to work if the number of digits is more than the number of 9's mentioned above.

Comment: @Hankton You can add more 9 then. But I doubt that you will need number grater than 10^15